# Unable to apply formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my daily dashboard in which I update the count, and if the complaint count of previous day is greater than I update uptrend observed in particular department.

I want the message the below the table automatically after I enter the count.

I tried applying condition `IF()` but did get through.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, then the following formula should work to get the desired output.*

*The following formula doesn't uses any `LAMBDA()` helper functions to perform `custom calculations` as well nor it uses any `volatile functions` which will `recalculate` anything anytime there is a change in any open workbook, as well as `volatile` functions slows down the working `engine/capacity` of `Excel`.*

Thats said:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A6</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, DailyDashBoard[#All],
     _Header, TAKE(_Data,1,COLUMNS(_Data)-1),
     _DataBody, DROP(TAKE(_Data,-2),,-1),
     _Filtered, FILTER(VSTACK(_Header,_DataBody),TAKE(_DataBody,1)<TAKE(_DataBody,-1)),
     _LastDay, TAKE(_Filtered,-1,1),
     _CustomDate, DAY(_LastDay)&
                  LOOKUP(DAY(_LastDay),ORDINALS)&" "&
                  TEXT(_LastDay,"mmm - ")&"Uptrend Observed in ",
     _Joined, TEXTJOIN({"(",",","), "},,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(DROP(_Filtered,,1),,1),3))&")",
     SUBSTITUTE(_CustomDate&_Joined,"), ",") and ",MAX(LEN(_Joined)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Joined,"),",))-2,1)))
```

---

- To explain I will start with, converted the ranges into `Structured References` aka `Tables`, in this forum, we usually suggest in using the same. Because it can resize the rows/columns without affecting the ranges/arrays taken within the formulas.
- Using `LET()` function it makes easier to read, assigns defined variables, eliminates redundant calculations.
- The variable `_Data` is defined for the whole `Structured References` `DailyDashBoard[#All]`
- Using `TAKE()` function extracting the `_Header` dynamically.
- Using `DROP()` & `TAKE()` extracting the `_DataBody` which represents the numbers and the dates, excluding the `Totals`
- Using `_Filtered` variable we are using `FILTER()` function to extract the `_Header` as well `_DataBody` stacked using `VSTACK()` to get the data as per the conditions mentioned aforesaid.
- `_LastDay` variable extract the date using the `TAKE()` function and we need only the last day not the previous one.
- `_CustomDate` variable is nothing but creates a concatenation of day and ordinal values along with the string that needs to follow after it.
- `_Joined` variable uses `TEXTJOIN()` function, before it converts the array into single using `TOCOL()` and then into a `2-dimensional` array to make it easier to combine.
- Last but not least, joining the `_CustonDate` with `_Joined` to get the desired output, but if one notes minutely it does uses `SUBSTITUTE()` function additionally to take care of the `and` which is needed if there is more one array of data.

---

**Test Case_1:**

[image]

---

**Test Case_2:**

[image]

---

**Addendum:**

Forgot to mention about the `ORDINALS` in the `LOOKUP()` function used in for variable `_CustomDate` it is a defined named in `Name Manager` using `VSTACK()`

[image]

---

```
=VSTACK(
    {1, "st"},
    {2, "nd"},
    {3, "rd"},
    {4, "th"},
    {21, "st"},
    {22, "nd"},
    {23, "rd"},
    {24, "th"},
    {31, "st"}
)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think I figured out what you want;
just need to know, do you update the date itself? Or do you add in another row every day?

Assuming your sheet starts at 'A1', and the text line starts in 'A6', try this formula in 'A6':

```
=TEXT(A3,"dd/mmm") & "Uptrend observed in" & IF(B3>B2 , "CC(" & B2 & "," & B3 & "), " , "") & IF(C3>C2 , "Pune Distribution(" & C2 & "," & C3 & ")" , "") & IF(D3>D2 , "Mumbai Distribution(" & D2 & "," & D3 & ")" , "") & IF(E3>E2 , "Quality(" & E2 & "," & E3 & ")" , "") & IF( F>F2 , "Production(" & F2 & "," & F3 & ")" , "") & IF(G3>G2 , "Website(" & G2 & "," & G3 & ")" , "") & IF(H3>H2 , "Online Payment(" & H2 & "," & H3 & ")" , "") & IF(I3>I2 , "IT(" & I2 & "," & I3 & ")", "")
```

It will not give you the 'and' at the end of whatever is last, but I hope it gets you closer to what you need.

I'll think of another method when I find some more time.

Comment: Sir, I update date my self. But doesn't matter it will be automated or manual date updation.
Thank you so much Sir for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(tbl,db[#All],
data,TAKE(DROP(tbl,1),-2),
header,TAKE(tbl,1),
diffByColumn,BYCOL(data,LAMBDA(c,INDEX(c,1,1)<INDEX(c,2,1))),
colsWithUptrend,DROP(FILTER(data,diffByColumn),,1),
headerWithUptrend,DROP(FILTER(header,diffByColumn),,1),
textUptrend,BYCOL(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(colsWithUptrend)),
                  LAMBDA(i,INDEX(headerWithUptrend,1,i)&" ("&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,CHOOSECOLS(colsWithUptrend,i))&"),")),
message,REDUCE(TEXT(INDEX(data,2,1),"tt.MM.")&" - Uptrend observed in ",textUptrend,LAMBDA(r,c,r&" "&c)),
LEFT(message,LEN(message)-1))
```

I use a table (called `db`) by this it expands per day you add - and you don't have to adjust the formula

`data` returns the last two rows of the table - which are then compared (`diffByColumn` which returns an array of `true` and `false`)

`textUptrend` creates the text parts per each column that has an uptrend.

As `TEXTJOIN` can not be applied to `textUptrend` `REDUCE` ist used to combine the text parts.

You will have to **adjust the `"tt.MM."` part** to your regional settings: `TEXT(INDEX(data,2,1),"tt.MM.")`

[image]

Comment: Ma'am, I think there is a typo, there shouldn't be `Pune Distribution` and `Quality` is missing. You may need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MayukhBhattacharya
Never though much deep about excel. Learnt a lot because of this...!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ike
Never though much deep about excel. Learnt a lot because of this...!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you'd like to *auto-generate* the uptrend summary text?

There are multiple parts to that line of text:

1. the maximum date (or final row of data ... )
2. for any column where trend > 0, you need the column header text
3. for any column where trend > 0, you need the values of the two last data points/rows

I suggest you break down the sentence and calculate each component separately in other rows or columns or (better yet) another tab altogether. Although the single-formula solutions look very effective, I normally suggest a component-based approach will be easier to bug check, change, pass onward to colleagues, and may result in tools or approaches you can reuse later.

Assuming you *must* leave this data in this format ... I suggest you add rows at the bottom of the data (after the Trend row) and put the component calculations there. Then, hide those rows and reference them in your sentence formula.

This is the fastest solution that came to mind. It does not exactly match your desired text, but it should be easy to add or remove data columns and otherwise maintain:

[image: Solution Proposed - ExcelScreenshot]

For a production report or your daily use, hide rows 5-7. To make things grammatically correct (commas, the closing 'and', etc.), you can further pretty-fy the text using various IF() conditions. That does not look the main issue in question.

Your formulas can be even shorter and clearer if:

- put the trend data & summary sentence at the top of the table, then reverse the date order (newest on top)
- Use the relative row/column argument of ADDRESS()

  Trend cells: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2, COLUMN()))

  Summary cells: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()))&" ("&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3, COLUMN()))&", "&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2, COLUMN()))&")"&", "

  Uptrend cells: =IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN()))>0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())), "")

  Report cell: =TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-5,COLUMN()-1,)),"DD MMM")&"  - Uptrends Observed in: "&CONCAT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN()+7)))